# GUI - compress a folder in tar.gz format skips the backup files (files ending with "~")

Tags: backup, 20.10, tar, gzip

If I have these example files in the folder "Example":

```
text1.txt
text1.txt~
text2.txt
text2.txt~
text3.txt
text4.txt
```

After the compression with mouse right-click and click "Compress..." in "Example.tar.gz" and afterwards decompress, I obtain only these files:

```
text1.txt
text2.txt
text3.txt
text4.txt
```

Why?

Ubuntu 20.10 Desktop 64-bit freshly installed.

Comment: What exact GUI application are you using to create this tar.gz archive?

Comment: After the compression with mouse right-click and click "Compress..."

Comment: Okay so you're selecting files in the Nautilus file manager and then right click to compress them. I don't believe this offers the option to not ignore files named that way. You will probably need to do this from the command line with ```tar``` utility.

Comment: I have understand.

Comment: Ok, only with CLI then is possible, infact with CLI there are all files.